# Центрирование заднего фона

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, canvas

Возник вопрос, как имея картинку и ставя её на задний фон получить положение её центра в центре экрана пользователя.

Внизу привел 4 возможных случая:
1)Картинка совпадает по разрешению с экраном. 2)Картинка выше чем и экран и для сохранения центровки не показываться верхняя и нижняя часть.3)Картинка шире и уже боковые стороны урезаны.
4)Картинка больше по обеим осям и просто центрируется.
и еще есть 5 возможный случай , когда картинка меньше чем размер экрана пользователя и в том случае она просто растягивается равномерно до заполнения всей области с центрировкой. Скролл блокирую.

Поверх всего этого будет тег canvas и в нем будет уже анимация.

[image: Screen page]

```
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas></body>
```

Comment: Центр картинки - (х/2;у/2). Где х и у координаты конечного угла картинки

Comment: Мне не центр нужен, а как адаптивно сделать, чтобы центр картинки совпадал с центров экрана пользователя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотри, можно так:

```css
body {
  background: url(../img/img.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}
/*
  no-repeat - Картинка не будет повторяться много раз
  center - выравнивает картинку по горизонтали
  top - выравнивает картинку по вертикали
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю тебе поможет `background-position: x,y`
Вместо `X` экспериментально подставляешь значение в процентах, при котором картинка находится по центру, с `Y` также.
Блокировка скролла - `background-position: fixed`
А также `background-size: 100%`

Короче:

```
background-position: 50%,50%; //к примеру 50%.
background-size: 100%; // заполняет всего родителя.
background-position: fixed; //блокирует скролл.
```

Comment: С каких пор оно в скобках?

Comment: Ни с каких) спасибо, что сказал

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
background: url(../img/my-img.jpg) no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
}
```